# Software to get videos for different angles from a 360 degree video

Tags: gratis, video, video-editing, youtube

I have recently been intrigued by watching videos on youtube about how one can create an inexpensive hologram and project images to create a 3d effect. I wanted to take it a step further and explore the possibility of creating holograms out of 360 degree [videos](http://www.kolor.com/360-videos/#start) on youtube.

The most popular software that lets one 'stitch' different camera angles into a seamless 360 panorama is [kolor pano](http://www.kolor.com/360-videos/#start). But to get a 360 video in the form of an hologram, one would require the individual parts or 4/6 different camera angles to start with.

So my problem is two fold. One- Is there a software that would let me 'destitch' the 360 into different camera angles or input raw files that some user might have started out with( in case he/she used a camera rig). Two- If the answer to One is no. Then I would want to record the 360 degree video in 4/6 angles which I want and create a hologram out of it. Is there an automatic solution/software that lets me set the initial angle to watch a 360 video so that I can record it?

I hope I was able to explain myself clearly.

I am hoping to get a browser only solution but if there's any such software that doesn't run on any specific browser, I'll be happy to know as well. So operating system is not a constraint. However I am looking for a free and open source kind of software as this is for an experiment only.

**Summary:**

- must be able to create holograms out of 360° videos ('destitch' the 360 into different camera angles or input raw files that some user might have started out with)
- should run in a browser (addon or web-app)
- should come free of charge, open-source preferred

PS: I couldn't find many relevant tags for this question and I also don't know if this question is suitable for the forum. Any cooperation in this regard is also deeply appreciated. I'd be grateful if someone can create the virtual-reality tag.

Comment: Thanks, Vivek! I've updated it again, adding a summary (to make it easier to grasp) and the `gratis` tag. Hope that suits you. Good luck!